# Resizing container while obtaining the same SVG percentage width

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to obtain the same percent of the filled container with an SVG when resizing container.
[image]

as you can see when I resize the container of my SVG, it doesn't update, the width of SVG remains the same, not 80% of the container.

```
<svg width="80%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 100% 100%">
   <defs>
     <clipPath id="progress-clipping-mask">
         <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
     </clipPath>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to remain 80% of the container even if it changes its width?

Comment: can you share the full code?

Comment: With this preserveAspectRatio, the SVG maintains its h/w ratio, so you can't stretch the SVG horizontally only. Does that explain things?

Comment: Percentages are not valid in viewBox attributes

Comment: Even when I remove preserveAspectRatio it still doesn't stretch as I want to

Comment: @RobertLongson do you have better solution for this?

Comment: For what? The viewBox won't work if it's not valid

Comment: @RobertLongson For making this to work as I intended to. Do you think that I can achieve what I want to with viewBox? Valid values in viewBox will make it work?

Comment: No idea there's not enough code there to answer that. If you want more from us add a [mcve]